# Сортировка многомерного массива по возрастанию

Tags: javascript

Есть массив **arr**:

```
var arr= [
  {4,2,3},
  {7,5,6},
  {1,9,8}
]
```

Первое число в строке - это вес предмета. Второе - длина. Третье порядковый номер.

Как отсортировать этот массив по весу (первый элемент) от меньшего к большему, чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
{1,9,8},
{4,2,3},
{7,5,6}
```

Comment: и по какой логике это выстраивается? и вообще зачем? просто чтоб?

Comment: так нельзя задавать массивы. У вас в массиве объекты без названия полей.